# Fixing a git mess during a Pull Request

Tags: git, github, merge, pull-request, squash

I have a large series of git commits made during a pull request for a github project. I've been asked to squash all of the commits together, however since then I have made an incredible mess of merges, resets and accidentally merging over other commits that I've pulled to the repo whilst the PR has been underway.

What i'd like to be able to do, is simply copy the two files that are actually involved in the pull request to another directory, reset back to the very first commit I made for the PR, re-paste my new files with the latest changes and then commit them, so that the PR shows up with a single commit. Is this possible? Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

If you want it to look like a single commit, you'll need to use git squash. Is there a reason why you can't use this?